# How to add action to button in PyQt5 with clicked.connect

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

I am trying to add action to my button in PyQt5 using clicked.connect but for some reasons, as I type it seems the IDE would recognize **clicked** but when it gets to **.connect** it doesn't look like **.connect** is available as a command. Below is part of my code where I'm stuck. Any help is appreciated!

```
import PyQt5.QtWidgets as qtwidget
import PyQt5.QtGui as qtgui
import PyQt5.QtCore as qtcore


app = qtwidget.QApplication([])
class Button(qtwidget.QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, text, parent=None):
        super().__init__(text, parent=parent)
        button_policy = self.sizePolicy()
        button_policy.setVerticalPolicy(button_policy.Policy.Minimum)
        self.setSizePolicy(button_policy)
        
        # Set text font style & size
        self.setFont(qtgui.QFont('Helvetica', 20))
        
        
        self.clicked.connect(self.update_label) # connect does not seem to be recognized
        
    def update_label(self, text, target):
        target.setText(text)
```

[image]

Comment: The real questions you should ask is: Did you try to run it? Does it work? Remember that IDE warnings are *not* errors, nor mean that your code is certainly wrong.

Comment: `clicked` is a valid `pyqtSignal` and connect is method of it.. so `connect` method might not be shown by IDE, but keep in mind it is valid.. for all `pyqtSignal`. But you should check what is emitted by that signal and then connect it to proper slot/function that are accepting those arguments

Comment: Thank you all. @musicamante -> you're correct. I ignored the uncolored word connect and run my code. I eventually succeeded. now I know better. Thank you, sir!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the feedback provided in the comment by **musicamante** to ignore the uncolored word **connect** and run the code and it worked just fine. Moving forward, I should probably not assume that if the IDE doesn't color (recognize) a word that doesn't mean it's not going to work.

Comment: The basic concept is that IDE, as smart as they could be, cannot evaluate objects accessed dynamically. For instance, if you have `a` and `b` that have declared an `x` attribute, the IDE will probably consider `a.x` and `b.x` as valid code. But if you have the object `z` that is actually a list including `a` and `b` and try to access those items using the indexes of `y` with the variable `z`, the IDE is not able to evaluate those values, since those are evaluated dynamically: you *may know* that `y` is 0, `z[y]` corresponds to `a` and `z[0].x` is valid, but the IDE is not capable of that.